# change Image and save position in list view when button is played

Tags: java, android, listview

I have a button in list view to play music.when a user click on this button,my music played and image of my button change also.
Now when user click on play button , I can change the image but there is two issue
that i couldn't handle it.
first I want when the user click to other position , My button (last position) images change to the other picture.
second when I scroll the list view, they disappear and there is no sign which position is playing. 
here is my code:
this my paly method:

```
   private void play(int index) {
    mediaPlayer.release();
    index++;
    String s = "mp3/a" + index + ".mp3";


    AssetFileDescriptor afd;
    try {
        afd = getAssets().openFd(s);
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(),   afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
        mediaPlayer.prepare();
        mediaPlayer.start();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and here is my paly button:

```
      play.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                if (rowView != lastview || mediaPlayer == null) {

                    play.setImageResource(R.drawable.played);
                    play(position);
                    if (lastview != null)
                        lastview = rowView;
                } else {

                    mediaPlayer.release();
                    lastview = null;
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: you have to create boolean variables to maintain the button clicked .............

Comment: how to do that?@sushildlh

Comment: you have to create array of boolean of your list size and make true if button clicked on that postion. check condition outside your button click .. if boolean true change button

Comment: would you please tell me with code, i am new with android

Comment: could you post your adapter code?

Comment: here is my whole code http://pastebin.com/embed_iframe/55JMqS9r @NaveenShriyan

Comment: i have changed your code and added some hint follow that: http://pastebin.com/kQNbD3nP

Comment: noting changed , the same as before :-((@NaveenShriyan

Comment: post ur changed code..

Comment: wait a minutes. you know I want all these happen in my play(my button) on click as I mention in my question.here is what you said http://pastebin.com/J5MZupK4

Comment: pls check in onclicklistener : http://pastebin.com/jCmwfzPB

Comment: when the new position selected , the last one must be change. the new position is play so the image must be play. the last position image must be played. I want this :-((( by the way thnx